# WPF: DataTrigger is not triggering inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

My requirement is to change foreground color to white if the background color of the Grid cell is Red.

I am using below template for the cell. But, its not triggering.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NumericThreeDecimalCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="Value"
                 StringFormat="###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.000;(###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.000)" />
        </TextBlock.Text>
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <Binding Path="Value"
                   Converter="{StaticResource negativeToBrushConvertor}" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>


    </TextBlock>

    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>                    
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Background.Color,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="#FF0000">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>                    
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
</DataTemplate>`
```

Let me know if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: What is a "grid cell" in this case?

Comment: I am using Devexpress gridControl. GridColumn's CellTemplate property is binded to this datatemplate.

Answer (score 0):

A local value, such as the returned by your `negativeToBrushConverter`, takes precedence over a value set by a style setter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

So no matter what you set the `Foreground` property to in your `Style`, it won't be applied unless you remove this part:

```
<TextBlock.Foreground>
    <Binding Path="Value" Converter="{StaticResource negativeToBrushConvertor}" />
</TextBlock.Foreground>
```

You should set the default value for the `Foreground` property in the `Style`. And you should set the `AncestorType` of the `{RelativeSource}` to whatever the property of your cell is:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="Value" StringFormat="###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.000;(###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.000)" />
        </TextBlock.Text>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="Value" Converter="{StaticResource negativeToBrushConvertor}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Background.Color,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dxg:GridCellContentPresenter}}" Value="#FF0000">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But, it still doesn't work. I tried commenting negativeToBrushConvertor but still datatrigger is not triggering. I used ancestorType as u  suggested.